# Как сделать такой изогнутый блок?

Tags: css3, html5

Как этот желтый прямоугольник также выгнуть в css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: думаю что `svg` в самый раз будет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант решения с `SVG`, не очень точный но можно доработать.

```html
<svg viewBox="-9.232 85.613 1040 580" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="510.768" y1="687.087" x2="510.768" y2="1267.871" id="gradient-0" gradientTransform="matrix(0, -1.807222, 1.807222, 0, -1255.486033, 1235.110107)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color: rgb(222, 177, 66);"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.458" style="stop-color: rgb(240, 222, 141);"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.695" style="stop-color: rgb(239, 218, 134);"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color: rgb(236, 201, 103);"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M 510.768 648.443 C 316.093 649.781 119.26 656.138 59.591 666.005 C 21.576 666.005 -9.242 635.187 -9.242 597.172 C -7.744 547.169 -6.445 459.665 -5.902 375.613 C -6.445 291.561 -7.744 204.057 -9.242 154.054 C -9.242 116.039 21.576 85.221 59.591 85.221 C 119.26 95.088 316.093 101.445 510.768 102.783 C 705.443 101.445 902.276 95.088 961.945 85.221 C 999.96 85.221 1030.778 116.039 1030.778 154.054 C 1029.28 204.057 1027.981 291.561 1027.438 375.613 C 1027.981 459.665 1029.28 547.169 1030.778 597.172 C 1030.778 635.187 999.96 666.005 961.945 666.005 C 902.276 656.138 705.443 649.781 510.768 648.443 Z" style="fill: url(#gradient-0);"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: bx:guide что это такое?

Comment: забыл убрать, спасибо что напомнили)

Comment: @DaniilLoban как доработать SVG не подскажите? Просто мне вот всегда было интересно как создать изображение своё в SVG или например в этой картинке изгиб побольше сделать, это мне нужно изучить коды SVG?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи я пользуюсь удобной программой [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/) остальное ловкость рук)

Comment: @DaniilLoban спасибо, гляну)

Comment: @DaniilLoban, я с недавних пор настолько приноровился, что для простых фигур даже лень вкладку с редактором открывать :)